# How to identify hardware RAID controller on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, raid

I'm trying to identify hardware RAID on Linux :

```bash
$ lspci -nnd ::0104 -k
02:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] [1000:005d] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell PERC H730 Mini [1028:1f49]
        Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
        Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
$ lspci -d ::0104 -m
02:00.0 "RAID bus controller" "Broadcom / LSI" "MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader]" -r02 "Dell" "PERC H730 Mini"
$ lsscsi
[0:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sda
[0:2:1:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdb
[0:2:2:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdc
[0:2:3:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdd
[0:2:4:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sde
[0:2:5:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdf
[0:2:6:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdg
[0:2:7:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdh
[0:2:8:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdi
[0:2:9:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdj
[0:2:10:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdk
[0:2:11:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdl
[0:2:12:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdm
[0:2:13:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdn
[0:2:14:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdo
[0:2:15:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdp
[0:2:16:0]   disk    DELL     PERC H730 Mini   4.27  /dev/sdq
$ cat /sys/class/block/sd?/device/model | sort -u
PERC H730 Mini
```

EDIT0: The Dell EMC OpenManage Server Administrator v10 says :

```bash
$ sudo omreport storage controller | grep Name
Name                                          : PERC H730 Mini
```

I have installed `inxi` from the RedHat EPEL repository and it says this :

```bash
$ sudo inxi -Rxxx
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] driver: megaraid_sas
    v: 07.714.04.00-rh1 port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 1000:005d rev: N/A class-ID: 0104
```

Is it a `Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108` controller or a `Dell PERC H730 Mini` RAID controller ?

P.S. : I have found this very useful documentation to help using RAID on Linux : https://hwraid.le-vert.net

Comment: That HWRaid documentation looks very useful for anyone maintaining various types of server hardware; however, it looks like it hasn't been updated recently, as it doesn't mention the fact that the ownership of the MegaRAID/FusionMPT product lines went from LSI to Avago and then to Broadcom. Anyway, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s both: it’s a Dell PERC H730 Mini controller, which is an OEM controller using the [LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 controller chip](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-on-chip/sas-3108).

This sort of setup is very common. The controller chip identifies itself as the PCI device, and the OEM adds their information as the PCI subsystem; that way, device drivers match against the PCI ids without needing to be updated for every OEM variant, but the OEM is identified for scenarios where that’s useful (*e.g.* for users, or if an OEM variant needs special handling in the driver).

Most systems have a number of devices using this technique; run

```
lspci -v | grep -B1 Subsystem:
```

to list them.